# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

```
public partial class addtheatre : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    bal objbal = new bal();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             DataSet ds = objbal.getid();
            int s;
            string d = "9T000";
            string c = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            if (c == "")
            {
                s = 1;
                d = "9T000" + s;
            }
            else
            {

              s = Convert.ToInt32(c);
                s = s + 1;
                if (s < 999)
                {
                    d = "9T000" + s;
                }
                //s = Convert.ToInt32(c);
                else if (s == 1000)
                {
                    d = "T1000";
                }
                else if (s > 1000)
                {
                    d = "T1000" + s;
                }

            }
            TextBox1.Text = d.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

while converting  it is showing as error(input string was not in a correct format).
In database I have taken `d` as `varchar`.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the error is coming from here:

```
s = Convert.ToInt32(c);
```

If the value of `c` is not a string representation of an integer (e.g. `"123"`) you get an exception here. You can inspect the value of `c` in a debugger (e.g. inside Visual Studio) to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error is coming from here:

try below code

```
int.TryParse(c,out s );
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the and given by Mark Byers..
you should probably use 
`int.TryParse(string)` or `int.Parse(string)` to convert string to int.